# MySQL and PHP - how to display all rows where field value equals x?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a database table (ff_projections) that contains the following fields:

```
ID  Player  Position    Team    Pass_Yds    Pass_TDs    Int_Thrown  Rush_Yds    Rush_TDs    Rec_Yds Rec_TDs Receptions  Fumbles Extra_Pts   FG  Sacks   Int_Caught  Def_TD  ST_TD   Shutouts    Overall_Pts Total_Fantasy_Pts
```

What I want is to display all rows where Position = QB. Only certain fields would appear in
the rows though.

Like this:

```
SELECT Player, Team, Pass_Yds, Pass_TDs, Int_Thrown, Rush_Yds, Rush_TDs, Overall_Pts, Total_Fantasy_Pts  FROM ff_projections WHERE Position = 'QB';
```

and then display the results in a table on the web page.

Comment: it would be helpful to post a couple sample rows, what you think it should be showing up and what it is actually showing up.

Comment: @phpmeh My interpretation is that the query is fine, but the OP doesn't know how to execute the query and output the data in PHP.

Comment: Michael - that is it exactly :) I generally know the logic of what I want to do, but not necessarily the correct syntax needed to execute it.

Comment: Here is a more general solution, that will print the result of any query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970936/how-to-echo-out-table-rows-from-the-db-php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Player, Team, Pass_Yds, Pass_TDs, Int_Thrown, Rush_Yds, Rush_TDs, Overall_Pts, Total_Fantasy_Pts FROM ff_projections WHERE Position = 'QB' ORDER BY Pass_Yds DESC;");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Player'];
  echo $row['Team'];
  ....
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Now how would I establish a default SORT BY? For example, when those rows display, I want them to be in order of the highest # of passing yards (Pass_Yds) first.

Comment: I figured it out :) I added ORDER BY Pass_Yds DESC and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @user1255168 This example has a static filter value in it. Be careful if you pass trough user input (escape it properly).

Comment: FWIW, here is an example using newer `mysqli` interface: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp  It also shows a nicer output per row.

Comment: Here is a more general solution, that will print the result of any query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970936/how-to-echo-out-table-rows-from-the-db-php