# How to pull data from MySQL with PHP into rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure what I am missing.  The page loads with the table but does not pull any data into the rows. I connected to the database and have pulled data before I edited the code to this.  And the first line does show the 9 rows I have.

```
<?php if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) : ?>
        <?php

        print '<table class="col-md-12">
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-1">Category</th>
                <th class="col-md-2">Subcategory</th>
            </tr>
 <tr>'.$rowsfortable.'
</tr>
</table>';
//Get Category.


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $qry = "SELECT * FROM general_category WHERE categoryID = {$row['categoryID']}";
            $tmpResult = qry($qry);
            $tmpRow = mysql_fetch_array($tmpResult);
            $category = $tmpRow['category_desc'];

            //Get Sub Category.
            $qry = "SELECT * FROM general_category WHERE categoryID = {$row['sub_categoryID']}";
            $tmpResult = qry($qry);
            if (mysql_num_rows($tmpResult) > 0) {
                $tmpRow = mysql_fetch_array($tmpResult);
                $sub_category = "/ " . $tmpRow['category_desc'];
                } else {
                    $sub_category = '';
                }
 for ($i=0; $i < count($row); $i++) {
            $rowsfortable = "print '<td>' '.$category.' '.$sub_category.'</td>'";


    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: there is an ordering issue in your code ...

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: Do I have to do the html after the php?

Comment: I wanted to make it work first, then convert it to pdo.

Comment: It'd save you a lot of time just to do it properly first, with either MySQLi or PDO - doesn't matter too much as long as you use prepared statements with placeholders. Neither is hard to learn.

Comment: I am redo pages of code one section at a time, but for some reason my mind is missing the structure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970936/how-to-echo-out-table-rows-from-the-db-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're printing out your table before `$rowsfortable` is ever assigned any value. PHP will execute in order.

Try moving the block of code that grabs your data and assigns it to `$rowsfortable` before the block that actually prints the table.